# Create a link which allows visitors to disable a plugin?

Tags: plugins, front-end

Is it possible to create a link that allows site visitors to disable a plugin?

I'm using a plugin called "any mobile theme" which automatically detects if the visitor is on a mobile device and automatically switches to a mobile-friendly version of the themes. This works very well, but I would like to give them option to view the full (desktop) version if they prefer.

Is it possible to create a frontend link to disable a plugin (the mobile theme switcher) to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Add a link to the plugin’s code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code …

```
// Embed Switch Links in Theme Via Shortcode
// [show_theme_switch_link]
function show_theme_switch_link_func( $atts ){
    $desktopSwitchLink  = get_option('show_switch_link_for_desktop');
    global $shown_theme;
    global $status;
    if ($shown_theme){
        $return = '<a rel="external" data-ajax="false" href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'?am_force_theme_layout=desktop" class="am-switch-btn godesktop">'.get_option('desktop_view_theme_link_text').'</a>';        
    } else {
        if ((!empty($status)) || ($desktopSwitchLink == 'yes')){
            $return = '<a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'?am_force_theme_layout=mobile" class="am-switch-btn gomobile">'.get_option('mobile_view_theme_link_text').'</a>';
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
add_shortcode('show_theme_switch_link', 'show_theme_switch_link_func');
```

… you should be able to print a switch link with:

```
echo show_theme_switch_link_func();
```